# Ansible - How to use lookup in remote servers

Tags: ansible

I have a file called `values.txt` on each of the server in the directory `/tmp/values.txt` and it has some values. And I have a `jinja` template and I am substituting some values from the the `values.txt`

**But the problem is, when i use the `lookup` command it looks in the controller server and not the remote servers**

Here's what I tried:

```
- name: Create /etc/systemd/system/etcd.service
  template:
    src: etcd.service.j2
    dest: /etc/systemd/system/etcd.service
  vars:
    value_from_file: "{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/values.txt').split('\n') }}"
    vars_from_jinja: [SELF_NAME, SELF_IP, NODE_1_NAME, NODE_1_IP, NODE_2_NAME, NODE_2_IP, NODE_3_NAME, NODE_3_IP, NODE_4_NAME, NODE_4_IP]
    my_dict: "{{ dict(vars_from_jinja|zip(value_from_file)) }}"
```

How can I can this task remotely? Or is there another workaround to substitute the values to the jinja template?

PS: I can't fetch the `values.txt` to the controller because the content of `values.txt` in each server is slightly different from the other.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 3):

Use [slurp](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/slurp_module.html):

```yaml
- name: read remote values.txt
  register: values
  ansible.builtin.slurp:
    src: /tmp/values.txt

- name: Create /etc/systemd/system/etcd.service
  template:
    src: etcd.service.j2
    dest: /etc/systemd/system/etcd.service
  vars:
    value_from_file: "{{ (values.content | b64decode).split('\n') }}"
    vars_from_jinja: [SELF_NAME, SELF_IP, NODE_1_NAME, NODE_1_IP, NODE_2_NAME, NODE_2_IP, NODE_3_NAME, NODE_3_IP, NODE_4_NAME, NODE_4_IP]
    my_dict: "{{ dict(vars_from_jinja|zip(value_from_file)) }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

The lookup find the file (or stream) on the controller. If you file is on the remote node, you can't use the lookup

> Lookup plugins are an Ansible-specific extension to the Jinja2 templating language. You can use lookup plugins to access data from outside sources (files, databases, key/value stores, APIs, and other services) within your playbooks. Like all templating, lookups execute and are evaluated on the Ansible control machine. Ansible makes the data returned by a lookup plugin available using the standard templating system. You can use lookup plugins to load variables or templates with information from external sources.

try the cat file instead:

```
- name: read the values.txt
  shell: cat /tmp/values.txt
  register: data

- name: Create /etc/systemd/system/etcd.service
  template:
    src: etcd.service.j2
    dest: /etc/systemd/system/etcd.service
  vars:
    value_from_file: "{{ data.stdout_lines }}"
    vars_from_jinja: [ SELF_NAME, SELF_IP, NODE_1_NAME, NODE_1_IP, NODE_2_NAME, NODE_2_IP, NODE_3_NAME, NODE_3_IP, NODE_4_NAME, NODE_4_IP ]
    my_dict: "{{ dict(vars_from_jinja|zip(value_from_file)) }}"
```

Comment: Is the `data.stdout_lines` going to be an array?

Comment: data.stdout_lines, it's an list: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html. And if you want you cant pipe it to be sure: data.stdout_lines|list

Comment: i can't or i can?

Comment: you can pipe it

Comment: I will try your method now and ping you asap